# SWT Composit/Canvas Fit Image

Tags: java, image, swt, aspect-ratio

I am trying to fit an image to a composite (or a canvas) which can be resized with the window. When it does, I want to be sure it doesn't mess up the aspect ratio, so I wrote this code to override the print function:

```
      bazaarMenu.addPaintListener(new PaintListener() {
            public void paintControl(PaintEvent event) {
                Image image = SWTResourceManager.getImage(mainFrame.class, "/assets/SkyHub/resources/images/bazaarBackground.jpg");//get the image
                int w = bazaarMenu.getClientArea().width;//composite width
                int h = bazaarMenu.getClientArea().height;//composite height
                int iw = image.getBounds().width;//image width
                int ih = image.getBounds().height;// image height
                
                //these are the values of the width/height of the image if ratio is same with the 
                //composite's
                int w1 = ih * (w / h);
                int h1 = iw * (h / w);
                
                //Find which value can be used and draw the image
                if(w1 <= w)
                {
                    event.gc.drawImage(image, 0, 0, w1, ih, 0, 0, w, h);
                }
                else// if(w / h < 76 / 45)
                {
                    event.gc.drawImage(image, 0, 0, iw, h1, 0, 0, w, h);
                }
            }
       });
```

However, I cannot get the result I want. Either image streches or only a part of it can be seen. Is there any other way to do or maybe I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it, the problem was int being too inaccurate, here is the code if anyone is searching for a ratio code:

```
bazaarMenu.addPaintListener(new PaintListener() {
            @Override
            public void paintControl(PaintEvent event) {
                Image image = SWTResourceManager.getImage(mainFrame.class, "/assets/SkyHub/resources/images/bazaarBackground.jpg");
                float w = bazaarMenu.getClientArea().width;
                float h = bazaarMenu.getClientArea().height;
                float iw = image.getBounds().width;
                float ih = image.getBounds().height;
                float a = 0;
                
                if(w / h > iw / ih)
                {
                    a = ih - (ih * w - iw * h) / w;
                    event.gc.drawImage(image, 0, (int)(ih - a) / 2, (int)iw, (int)a, 0, 0, (int)w, (int)h);
                }
                else
                {
                    a = (w * ih) / h;
                    event.gc.drawImage(image, (int)(iw - a) / 2, 0, (int)a, (int)ih, 0, 0, (int)w, (int)h);
                }
                //event.gc.setFont(new Font( minionButton.getDisplay(), new FontData( "Arial", 10, SWT.BOLD )));
                //event.gc.drawText(" Canvas W: " + w + "\n Canvas H: " + h + "\n Image W: " + iw + "\n Image H: " + ih + "\n a: " + a + "\n Mode: " + ((w / h > iw / ih)? "landscape" : "portrait") + "\n Canvas ratio: " + (w / h) + "\n Image ratio: " + (iw / ih), 5, 5);
            }
        });
```